# Passing variables to 'helper_method's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, helper

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to pass some variables to an `helper_method` stated in my controller.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :method_name

  private

  def method_name # Here I would like to state\use something like 'def method_name(var1, var2)'
    ...
  end
end
```

Is it possible? If so, how should I code and how can I use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a function you do this:

> def method_name (param1,param2)

to call a function you do this:

> method_name (arg1, arg2)

Comment: I would like to state a method as you have stated and then make that to work (also) as an 'helper_method'.

Comment: each controller has it's own helper file or you can write helpers in the application helper file. it does not matter whether you have a helper method or not. passing variables is exactly the same.

Comment: So, can you be more prolific in your answer? I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: [this](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/49-using-helper-methods-in-ruby-on-rails) might help. Let me know if you still don't get it.

Comment: @theRealWorld link is broken