# How to call a controller method in an associated view file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a method in a controller file, and then call that method in the `index.html.erb` view file.

Here are both my index action and my custom method in the controller file:

```
def index
  @mustdos = current_user.mustdos
end

def calculates_mustdos_days_left
  ((mustdo.created_at + 7.days - Time.now) / ( 60 * 60 * 24)).round
end
helper_method :calculates_mustdos_days_left
```

And here is the relevant code from my associated my `index.html.erb` file:

```
<% @mustdos.each do |mustdo| %>
  <tr id="todo-<%= "#{mustdo.id}" %>">
    <td><%= calculates_mustdos_days_left %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I am getting this error:

```
NameError in Mustdos#index
```

And it is referencing this line from my `index.html.erb` view file

```
<td><%= calculates_mustdos_days_left %></td>
```

How can I resolve this?  Thanks.

Comment: Show the controller `Mustdos`..

Comment: where come from your `mustdo` variable in method `calculates_mustdos_days_left`?

Comment: @Зелёный `mustdo` probably OP defined as `getter`... May be, I'm not sure!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing variables to 'helper\_method's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827069/passing-variables-to-helper-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I try to leave my helper methods for when I need them to generate content/output for a view. When I want to calculate and return data regarding a particular Model instance, I either add that code to a Service or the model itself.

**app/models/must_do.rb**

```
def days_left
  ((self.created_at + 7.days - Time.now) / ( 60 * 60 * 24)).round
end
```

Then, in my view, it's easy to access this off the model's instance:

```
<% @mustdos.each do |mustdo| %>
  <tr id="todo-<%= "#{mustdo.id}" %>">
    <td><%= mustdo.days_left %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

For me, this is a cleaner implementation of the desired behavior. Wanted to offer it as an alternative/additional approach to @IS04's answer.

Comment: This is perfect.  I tried a version of this, and it was not working.  By looking at your code, I had `mustdo.created_at` instead of `self.created_at`.  This is working now.  Thanks all!

Comment: Sweet :)! Glad you've got it rocking!

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
helper_method def calculates_mustdos_days_left(mustdo)
  ((mustdo.created_at + 7.days - Time.now) / ( 60 * 60 * 24)).round
end
```

and then in your view file:

```
<% @mustdos.each do |mustdo| %>
  <tr id="todo-<%= "#{mustdo.id}" %>">
    <td><%= calculates_mustdos_days_left(mustdo) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

but instead controller methods you should use `helper` methods, also if your method is more general (related to model) and doesn't depend from view, you could define it in your `model` as @craig.kaminsky written

Comment: I placed the method in the `applcation_helper.rb` file, and added a spot for a parameter to be passed into the method, and now it is working.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. You can't call methods outside of the controller action you are in in your view. If you have a piece of logic like that you should really try to get it into a model. In this case I would put this method in the mustdo model.

But in those cases where putting the logic into a model does not make sense you can use helper namespaces. It is sort of a miscellaneous drawer for methods that don't quite fit anywhere, like display logic. Helpers go in the `app/helpers/` directory. By default there is a helper namespace file in there called `application_helper.rb`. Any method you put in there will be available in all your controllers and views.